# TensorFlow: run in parallel several versions of a Python script calling TF

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am refining a Python script that implements DQN algorithm based on Keras + TensorFlow. It is a very empirical and trial-and-error process, so I would like to run the script in background, and in the meantime tweak some hyperparameters within the code and run that second version in parallel. If I try to do that now, I receive an error because the GPU is being used. I am using a server via SSH with an Intel Xeon and a single NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780 GPU. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow by default will preallocate all your free GPU memory at startup, to make sure we don't waste time waiting for individual memory allocations. If you want concurrent instances of tf running you can disable this by allowing the GPU heap to grow:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Note however that if your model can utilize the GPU with one version running you don't want to run two concurrently as it'll be slower.